# npm script not launching application correctly

Tags: typescript, npm, electron

I have an Aurelia typescript application. It is built using webpack and the Aurelia CLI. I am trying to run the application using electron.

I have the following in my packages.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nps",
    "test": "nps test",
    "electron": "electron ."
  },
  "main": "src/main.js"
```

and a very simple electron.js file just to test electron is working:

```
console.log('running!')
```

My issue is that if I run the command:

```
npm run electron
```

Then the console outputs the following:

```
electron .
```

then throws a an error in a pop up window:

[image]

I can get the application to work if I run the elxplicit command 'electron .' in a terminal window. If I run this then I get the following output:

```
electron .

running!
```

which is the expected behavior.

My question is twofold. What is the 'electron .' command doing? I know that this command fires up the electron application, but what is the 'space dot' doing? Αnd how do I google around this syntax, as google doesn't seem to register spaces or dots?

The second part to my question is, why is npm acting differently to a direct entry into the console, rather than running the same command as an npm script?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

PS: my dev environment is windows 10

Comment: did you install electron globally or locally in your project? Btw. `electron .` means "run the script marked as "main" in your package.json in this directory with electron", with the dot being the relative path to your current working directory. You could also run `electron src/main.js` with the same effect.

Comment: @Rhayene, Thanks! That would make sense now, once you know it. I first installed electron locally '--save-dev'. Then when that didn't work I installed it globally also with '-g'.

Comment: ok, npm scripts run with the locally installed modules. When calling `electron .` on your command line you call the globally installed instance, that itself- and here comes the confusing part from electron - calls the locally installed one if present (thanks electron I guess?). But I don't know if this is your problem, so could you install electron locally again and run the npm script again, please?